# jQuery/JavaScript: Initiate and terminate a loop with the same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I want to build a button that when I click it, the function in JavaScript associated with it initiates (so a loop inside it start doing something).

If I click it again before the loop inside the function finishes, the loop will terminates.

If I click it again after the loop inside the function has already finished, the loop will just start as usual.

How do I do this with the following code?
Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="startstop" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="count()">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function count() {
    var val = 0;
    var loop = setInterval(function(){
        val++;
        if (val > 1000} {
           clearInterval(loop);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: You already know you can `clearInterval` with the value returned from `setInterval` - so whats the problem?

Comment: It's pretty simple logic - store the loop id outside of the function, make sure you also clear the id variable when the interval is cleared, and base your logic around that

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var loop; 
function count() {
    var val = 0;
      if (loop) {
        clearInterval(loop);
        loop = null;
      }
      else{
     loop = setInterval(function(){
        val++;
        console.log(val);
        if (val > 1000) {
           clearInterval(loop);
           loop = null;
        }
    }, 100);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `loop` variable in global scope and everytime the user clicked stop previous loop if it's already started if not start it.

Hope this helps.

```js
var loop=null;

count = function () {
    var val = 0;

    //Stop previous loop if it's already started
    if(loop!=null){
        clearInterval(loop);
        loop=null;
    }else{
        loop = setInterval(function(){
            val++;
            console.log(val);

            $('span').text(val);

            if (val >= 20) {
                clearInterval(loop);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="startstop" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="count()">Count</button>
<span>0</span>
```

Comment: OP asked that when the interval was running, the button would stop it. This code simply restarts the interval from scratch

Comment: Oooh thanks @freefaller you're right, updated my answer, check now please.

Comment: You need to clear the `loop` variable on the automatic `clearInterval` otherwise you have to click the button twice to re-start it.  I always find it best to test code before releasing to the public domain ;-)

Comment: Yes that true, i'm sorry for the misunderstanding of question :), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of doing work for people, but on this occasion I'll succumb...

You need to store the internal ID outside of the function, and base your process on that.  If the ID is not set, start the interval, if it is set stop the interval.

Note, that I've massively reduced the length of interval, and the number of times it fires for this example...

```js
var _intervalId = -1;
function count() {
  if (_intervalId == -1) {
    var val = 0;
    _intervalId = setInterval(function(){
      val++;
      if (val > 200) {
        clearInterval(_intervalId);
        _intervalId = -1
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "stopped automatically";
      }
    }, 10);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "started";
  } else {
    clearInterval(_intervalId);
    _intervalId = -1;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "stopped manually";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="count();return false">Click Here</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had fun building a small class for this. Feel free to use.

```js
// Counter class
function Counter(callback, speed, max, init){
  var loop = null;
  this.callback = callback;
  this.value = init || 0;
  this.max = max;
  
  function count(){
    if (this.max && this.value >= this.max) {
      clearInterval(loop);
      loop = null;
    } else {
      this.value++;
    }
    this.callback(this.value);
  }
  
  this.start = function(){
    if(!this.isStarted){
      loop = setInterval(count.bind(this), speed);
    }
  };
  
  this.stop = function(){
    if(this.isStarted){
      clearInterval(loop);
      loop = null;
    }
  }
  
  Object.defineProperty(this, "isStarted", { get: function(){
    return !!loop;
  }});
}

// Usage example.

var result = document.getElementById("counter");
var button = document.getElementById("startstop");

// Create the counter and the callback.
var counter = new Counter(function(val){
  result.innerHTML = val;
}, 100, 1000);
// Init the result value.
result.innerHTML = counter.value;

// Listen for click events on the button.
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(counter.isStarted){
    counter.stop();
  } else {
    counter.start();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
<button id="startstop">Toggle</button>
```